# Dividir texto inteiro em pedaços javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Boa tarde galera do stackoverflow

Eu estou precisando dividir o texto que recebo de um retorno de um ajax.
Esse meu retorno tem o seguinte padrão

Ele começa com o que vai ser o value, o resto vai ser o conteúdo de um option, terminando no fila de espera ou vagas disponíveis, como segue o exemplo abaixo.

> ```
> 222/05/2017 a 26/05/2017 em Belo Horizonte - PaperCut MF Técnico Presencial (34 hrs) - Fila de espera307/08/2017 a 11/08/2017 em Belo Horizonte - PaperCut MF Técnico Presencial (34 hrs) - Vagas disponíveis
> ```

Como que conseguirei fazer essa divisão... eu to sem ideias, só preciso do raciocínio logico para isso...

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56094/discussion-on-question-by-gabrielfalieri-dividir-texto-inteiro-em-pedacos-javasc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de achar melhor esse retorno ser um `array`, eu consegui separar dessa maneira:

```js
var response = "222/05/2017 a 26/05/2017 em Belo Horizonte - PaperCut MF Técnico Presencial (34 hrs) - Fila de espera307/08/2017 a 11/08/2017 em Belo Horizonte - PaperCut MF Técnico Presencial (34 hrs) - Vagas disponíveis";

var data = response.split(/(\d+)(?=(?:\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\sa))/);

var obj = {};
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  obj[data[i]] = data[++i];  
}

console.log(obj);
```

Dessa forma a variável `obj` vai receber o id como `key` e o texto correspondente como `value`.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu caro